# SVG: simplify path to remove curves?

Tags: path, svg, inkscape

I have a svg file which contains complex paths with bezier curves in it.
I need to convert this path-data to use it for html map-area's, so I in fact I need just the coordinates  (but for large curves, it would be very nice to have some coordinates 'between' the two end-points.

I tried Inkscape's simplify path function, but those paths still contain curves...

Is there any tool or formula to convert these curves into simple coordinates?

Maybe another Inkscape output-format that doesn't use curves in its coordinates?

Comment: If you just need the coordinates, can't you extract them out of the SVG file using a script?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Inkscape:

1. Select the *Edit Path By Nodes* tool (<kbd>F2</kbd>)
2. Click on your path to select it
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all the nodes in that path
4. Click the **Insert new nodes into selected segments**. Repeat this to represent the shape of the curve/s in as much detail as you need.
5. Then click *Make Selected Segments Lines*

These options are on the toolbar at the top - the plus icon and the straight diagonal line between two square nodes.

[image: screenshot of make selected segments lines]

Answer (score 9):

For automation, try the included `Flatten Bezier` extension in Inkscape. Description [here](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=4308).

Comment: This works so much better than "Make Selected Segments Lines", as it'll actually add nodes to approximate the curves.

Comment: This is the correct solution. It addresses the `but for large curves, it would be very nice to have some coordinates 'between' the two end-points` part in the question. The extension is under `Extensions` > `Modify Path` > `Flatten Beziers...` in Inkscape 0.92.

Comment: It is possible to use "Make Selected Segments Lines" to do this.  However the accepted answer completely missed the critical step.  I've edited it to add this step: use "Insert new nodes into selected segment" before "Make Selected Segments Lines"

Answer (score 1):

There is more technical way to simplify SVG path - https://github.com/mattdesl/simplify-path

```
var path = [ [250, 150], [250, 150], [25, 25], [24, 25], [10, 10] ]
var tolerance = 10
path = simplify(path, tolerance)
//result:
//[ [ 250, 150 ], [ 25, 25 ], [ 10, 10 ] ]
```