# Android launcher icon still showing default in Android Oreo

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, mipmaps

I changed my application launcher icon using Android Studio 3.0.1:

```
File -> Image Asset
```

In Android 8.1, the icon looks like below image:

[image]

My `AndroidManifest` details

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

I double checked the icons.`ic_launcher` and `ic_launcher_round` are my new icons.

Comment: What I understood is that you are replacing default `ic_launcher` to your icon?? And while replacing this icon the launcher icon still shows its default icon. Am I right??

Comment: @MashukKhan yes,I replaced icon with the help of android studio

Comment: For some weird reason i am having same issue. I used legacy option to update launcher icons. Checked i don't have any default icon in my project. New icon is shown in the launcher but recent tray and settings still show default icon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved my issue by changing

> `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'`

to

> `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'`

in project `build-gradle`

```
dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

this will cause a flavoring issue ,that can be solved by adding

> flavorDimensions "default"

in application `build-gradle`

```
android {

...
flavorDimensions "default"
defaultConfig {
}


}
```

this may help some one with same problem.

Comment: This causes a build break with Android Studio 3.4.1 where `classpath` is not recognized.

Answer (score 14):

Best solution is delete mipmap-anydpi-v26  folder then app will take default icon. In android studio Project mode go to this package

> res/mipmap-anydpi-v26

delete it and rebuild and Run program.

Comment: Deleting the `mipmap-anydpi-v26` isn't the best solution.  It just avoid the issue which the OP doesn't have the right files to support new feature introduced in 8.0 (API 26).  His project contains not only his icon (ic_launcher for up to 7.0, ic_launcher_round for 7.1), but also new and default `ic_launcher_background` and `ic_launcher_foreground` under drawable.

Answer (score 6):

**You Need Put Round Icon for 8.1**

```
 <application
    android:name=".aaa"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="aaa"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: It is already there in manifest      `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"`

Comment: check that it's your app icon or default one.

Comment: ic_launcher_round is defult one please check that

Comment: When we import using image assets it automatically replace with our new icon, I double checked the icons in my mipmap

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem - a default icon was showing up in the task switcher. What fixed it for me is **removing** the round icon from my manifest.

As per the documentation for [Adaptive icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive),

> You must **only** use the android:roundIcon attribute if you require a different icon asset for circular masks, if for example the branding of your logo relies on a circular shape.

(emphasis mine)

My app does not need a different asset for circular masks - removing the reference to the round icon from the manifest caused Android to show the correct launcher icon in the task switcher.

Comment: That worked for me too.

Comment: This solved it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio, use **Image Asset** to (re)create your icons.  On Windows, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. On Mac, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.  When you are done, save and overwrite existing files.  Then the problem will be fixed.

Most likely you'll provide your own icon and your background color (which will be just a resource in colors). Image Asset will created a set of new `ic_launcher_foreground.png`.  You'll find two set of (now) unused resources: `ic_launcher_background.xml` (which gives the green background with grid) and `ic_launcher_foreground.xml` (which gives the Droid head).  You can safely remove those files.

Comment: This is the only working solution for me on Android 8.1

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio Go to `File -> New -> Image Asset -> Then browse your launcher icon` which you want to use and click next to finish the process. Try to use 1024x1024 size image or at least 512px . See the picture below for clear understanding.

Step 1: Go to `File -> New -> Image Asset`

[image]

Step 2: Then Choose your launcher image and click next to finish the process it will replace your current launcher image. See the image for other setting also like you must select `Icon Type: Adaptive and Legacy`

[image]

Comment: I did and it still picks the default drawable.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptoms, where my imported SVG image would not show up on API 26+, but it turned out to be an issue with the complexity of the source SVG. I opened the SVG in Inkscape, found a particularly complex path in the image then:

**Extensions > Modify Path > Flatten Beziers...**

As mentioned here: [SVG: simplify path to remove curves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386786/svg-simplify-path-to-remove-curves)

After re-importing the SVG it worked fine.