# Recent apps icon in React-native

Tags: react-native

I changed the default app icon and it appears fine in the app drawer, but on Android 8.0's recent apps the icon is still the default one.

Also when I try to uninstall the app, the Alert windows that opens contains the dafault react-native icon.

I tried looking on other posts and found [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329715/how-to-add-icons-to-react-native-app/34333915#34333915), but I already set those and even created a mipmap-ldpi (36x36) icon, but it still remains the same.

How can I change these icons?

I'm using React-native 0.59.1

[image: Android 8.0' recent apps screen]

Comment: I will suggest you to use https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/ and generate app icons for all sizes.

Comment: I used it for creating the mipmap folders, but it doesn't effect the recent apps icon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Android 8.0 and Above `Adaptive Launcher Icon` are used and for Versions below Android 8.0 we use `Legacy Launcher Icon`

You can try try to update icons using  `Image Asset Studio` -

To start Image Asset Studio, select Android in the `Project Window`. Right click on the `res` folder and `select New > Image Asset`. You have now opened Image Asset Studio. You can now create an `Adaptive Launcher Icon` or `Legacy Only Launcher Icon` as per your requirement by selecting `Icon Type`.

You can refer to this [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-update-the-launcher-icon-for-your-android-app--cms-30624) for more information.

Hope it works !

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried creating "Launcher icons (Adaptive and Legacy)" but the recent apps icon still remains the dafult one.
Any other idea?

Comment: check 'android:icon' in android manifest which icon it is referring to ?

Comment: I have android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" and android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round". I even tried deleting the roundIcon

Comment: replace ic_launcher with icon you want to add as app logo.Add the icon to @mipmaps inside res directory in android studio

Comment: That's what I did. It worked on the launcher icon but somehow in the recent apps it remains the default one. I also tried uploading to Google Play (you can download it and test if you would like)

Comment: can you share playstore link of the app?

Comment: Of course, sorry - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.integ

Comment: i came across some solution in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640049/android-launcher-icon-still-showing-default-in-android-oreo. you can try these i think it will resolve your issue.

Comment: The mipmap-anydpi-v26 folder was created after your first suggestion and it indeed generated all of the icons files in the mipmap folder, but unfortunately the behaviour is still the same. I'm getting really frustrated about it :\

Comment: Hey, just wanted to let you know that this is probably something with my phone. I tried it on the emulator and there isn't any issue at all. Thank you very much for your help!